# Load ONNX model in opencv2 fails with blob.type() assertion error

Tags: python, opencv, onnx

OS: Raspian GNU/Linux 9
Python: 3.6.6
OpenCV: 4.1.1

When I load an ONNX model in OpenCV DNN I get the following error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   /home/pi/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:505:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) blob.type() == 5 in function
>   'populateNet'

I'm training a mobilenet_v2 ssd model in PyTorch, then exporting model.eval() to ONNX. onnx.checker.check_model() seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Might have something to do with CV_32F data type format in my export?

Comment: try newest opencv version

Comment: @Micka updated to 4.2.0-dev build from source and still running into this issue. Any other ideas?